# Motorola Razer v3i Modem detection error with Kannel

Tags: kannel

Please help me I am getting this error on running the bearerbox

```
[root@localhost sbin]# ./bearerbox -v 1 /usr/local/smskannel.conf
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: Debug_lvl = 1, log_file = <none>, log_lvl = 0
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] WARNING: DLR: using default 'internal' for storage type.
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: DLR using storage type: internal
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13003.
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: BOXC: 'smsbox-max-pending' not set, using default (100).
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: Set SMS resend frequency to 60 seconds.
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: SMS resend retry set to unlimited.
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <FAKE> disabled.
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <(null)> disabled.
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: configuration doesn't show modemtype. will autodetect
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: ----------------------------------------
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [7] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: opening device
2012-04-30 11:56:28 [13417] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
2012-04-30 11:56:31 [13417] [7] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: speed set to 115200
2012-04-30 11:56:33 [13417] [7] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: Closing device
2012-04-30 11:56:33 [13417] [7] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: detect speed is 115200
2012-04-30 11:56:33 [13417] [7] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: opening device
2012-04-30 11:56:34 [13417] [7] INFO: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: speed set to 115200
2012-04-30 11:56:36 [13417] [7] PANIC: AT2[/dev/ttyACM0]: Cannot detect modem and generic not found
2012-04-30 11:56:36 [13417] [7] PANIC: ./bearerbox(gw_panic+0xc2) [0x80cc0e2]
2012-04-30 11:56:36 [13417] [7] PANIC: ./bearerbox [0x806ca62]
2012-04-30 11:56:36 [13417] [7] PANIC: ./bearerbox [0x806d5f1]
2012-04-30 11:56:36 [13417] [7] PANIC: ./bearerbox [0x80c2971]
2012-04-30 11:56:36 [13417] [7] PANIC: /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0xb9649b]
2012-04-30 11:56:36 [13417] [7] PANIC: /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e) [0xaed42e]
```

I am using Motorola Razer v3i using usb cable with Redhat. The device is also detected in /dev as ttyACM0 
This is my smskannel.conf

---

```
group = core
admin-port = 13003
smsbox-port = 13004
admin-password = bar
#status-password = foo
#admin-deny-ip = ""
#admin-allow-ip = ""
#log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
#log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
#unified-prefix = "+923,0092,0;+,00"
#access-log = "/tmp/access.log"
#store-file = "kannel.store"
#ssl-server-cert-file = "cert.pem"
#ssl-server-key-file = "key.pem"
#ssl-certkey-file = "mycertandprivkeyfile.pem"

#---------------------------------------------
# SMSC CONNECTIONS

group = smsc
smsc = fake
smsc-id = FAKE
port = 10000
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1

#this is for Motorola Razer V3i

group = smsc
smsc = at
modemtype = auto
device=/dev/ttyACM0
my-number = 00923478847037
sms-center= 00923455000010
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1
log-level = 0

#-----------------Modem Group------------
group = modems
id = Motorola
name = "Motorola"
init-string = "AT+C=1"
need-sleep = true
enable-mms = true
speed = 115200
message-storage = "SM" 


#---------------------------------------------
# SMSBOX SETUP
#


group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = 13013
#sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
#log-file = "/tmp/smsbox.log"
#log-level = 0
#access-log = "/tmp/access.log"

#---------------------------------------------
# SEND-SMS USERS


group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar
#user-deny-ip = ""
#user-allow-ip = ""

#---------------------------------------------
# SERVICES


group = sms-service
keyword = nop
text = "You asked nothing and I did it!"


group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"
```

---

Please help me

Comment: Also sorry for pasting too much but I was unable to find the other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this init-string:

```
init-string = "AT+CMEE=2;+CNMI=3,1,0,0,0".
```

It worked for my Motorola Razr2 v8: I am able to send and receive messages. [This guy](http://old.nabble.com/Motorola-Razr-V3-SMS-Receive-td10272601.html) suggested the solution I provided and it worked for his Razr v3.

For a complete list of AT commands and explanations, I found [this reference](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53163558/AT-Commands-Reference-for-Motorola-Handsets)  very useful.

Comment: Thank you very much brother. I was able to solve this problem a month ago ..... really proud of people like you who are always there to share their knowledge .... .....Yes I used the same string it worked for me